# Problem with SWT Combobox addSelectionListener()

Tags: java, eclipse-rcp, eclipse-3.6

```
cmbCategory.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) {

        //Do things

    }
});
```

The above code works just fine when I make selection using the control itself, but does not fire when I try changing the index programmatically.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this could work:

```
cmbCategory.addModifyListener(new ModifyListener(){
    @Override
    public void modifyText(ModifyEvent event) {

        //Do things

    }
});
```